# Scrollbar location is wrong in layout : fit

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a Panel and in that panel I am loading grid dynamically. 
Here is code for panel

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    region: 'center',
    frame: true,
    scrollable: true,
    itemId: 'MyGrid',
    reference: 'MyGrid',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: []
}
```

and Sample of grid.

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.MYGrid", {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.MyGrid',
    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.filters.Filters',
        'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    ],
    emptyText: 'No data available.',
    disableSelection: true,
    margin: '3 3 0 3',
    collapsible: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    closable: true,
    columnLines: true,
    uniqueFields: [],
    });

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.fields = me.prepareFields(me.headersXmlDoc);
    me.columns = me.prepareColumns(me.headersXmlDoc);
    me.store = me.prepareGridStore(me.headersXmlDoc);
    this.callParent(arguments);
},
```

Now when Grid have enough data then both horizental and vertical scroll is coming correctly but When grid have less data with more columns scrollbar is coming down. I supposed just beow the last record but it comming in down.

All the grid is taking same height though it have a less record.

Example pic
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKdTb.png

I want scrollbar just below the last data. By debugging I found `layout : fit`
 But not sure how to overcome out from that.

Can anybody  help me that. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply **overflowY** as true for grid.I don't think there is some problem with fit layout.If above config doesn't work share some fiddle.